# Retrieve same key data from Firebase on all pages

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

So the problem is I'm trying to retrieve this data from the Firebase database, where each case study
represent one key of data, and what I get is the same data of the first key on all the case study pages.

**Data on the Firebase:**
[image]

**List of Case studies Page:**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XLgN7.png)

**Case Study Page:**
These are two different case studies yet have the same data.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceofn.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cRieJ.png)

I used Animated List at the beginning to retrieve the data but it gave me the same problem, so I
followed a Youtube Tutorial and used another way but the problem remains. I know I need to pass a key when the button is clicked to link each case study with its key but I'm not sure how.

Here is the code for more clarification:

***stu_case_study_view.dart***

Case Study Page

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/Model/stu_case_study_model.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/functions/database.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/widgets/back_button.dart';


class CaseStudyView extends StatefulWidget {
  final String csKey;
  CaseStudyView({this.csKey});

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CaseStudyView();
  }
}

class _CaseStudyView extends State<CaseStudyView> {
  bool _loading = false;
  List<CaseStudyModel> caseStudyList = [];

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final question1Controller = TextEditingController();
  final question2Controller = TextEditingController();
  final question3Controller = TextEditingController();
  final question4Controller = TextEditingController();
  final question5Controller = TextEditingController();

  
  DatabaseReference caseStudyInfo;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    caseStudyInfo = firebaseref.child('case_study');
    caseStudyInfo.once().then((DataSnapshot snap) {
      var keys = snap.value.keys;
      var data = snap.value;
      caseStudyList.clear();
      for (var key in keys) {
        CaseStudyModel csList = new CaseStudyModel(
          data[key]['title'],
          data[key]['description'],
          data[key]['body'],
          data[key]['question1'],
          data[key]['question2'],
          data[key]['question3'],
          data[key]['question4'],
          data[key]['question5'],
        );
        caseStudyList.add(csList);
      }

      setState(() {
        print('Length : $caseStudyList.length');
      });
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
     
        Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Case Study'), //Temp data
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: caseStudyList.length == 0
            ? new Text('No Case Studies Uploaded')
            : new ListView.builder(
                itemCount: caseStudyList.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, index) {
                  return _caseStudy(
                    caseStudyList[index].title,
                    caseStudyList[index].description,
                    caseStudyList[index].body,
                    caseStudyList[index].question1,
                    caseStudyList[index].question2,
                    caseStudyList[index].question3,
                    caseStudyList[index].question4,
                    caseStudyList[index].question5,
                  );
                }),
      ),

  
    );
  }

  _showAlertDialog(BuildContext context) {
    Widget cancelButton = FlatButton(
        child: Text('Cancel'),
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop());
    Widget submitButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text('Submit'),
      onPressed: () {
        if (_formKey.currentState.validate()) {
          firebaseref.child('case_study').push().set({
            "question1": question1Controller.text,
            "question2": question2Controller.text,
            "question3": question3Controller.text,
            "question4": question4Controller.text,
            "question5": question5Controller.text,
          });

          Navigator.of(context, rootNavigator: true).pop();
          Navigator.pop(context);
        }
      },
    );

    // set up the AlertDialog
    AlertDialog alert = AlertDialog(
      title: Text('Alert'),
      content: Text('Are you sure you want to submit?'),
      actions: [
        cancelButton,
        submitButton,
      ],
    );

    // show the dialog
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      // barrierDismissible: false,
      builder: (BuildContext cxt) {
        return alert;
      },
    );
  }

  Widget _caseStudy(
      String title,
      String description,
      String body,
      String question1,
      String question2,
      String question3,
      String question4,
      String question5) {
    return _loading
        ? Container(
            child: Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            ),
          )
        : Container(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 0, 10, 10),
            child: Form(
                key: _formKey,
                child: Container(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                    horizontal: 20,
                    vertical: 20,
                  ),
                  child: ListView(
                      scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(
                          title,
                          style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 18,
                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                              height: 2,
                              color: Colors.deepPurple),
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                        Text(
                          'Description:',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                          child: Text(
                            description,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            maxLines: null,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          'Case Study:',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Container(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                          child: Text(
                            body,
                            textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                            maxLines: null,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Divider(),
                        Text(
                          'Questions:',
                          textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                          style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '1/ ' + question1,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: question1Controller,
                          validator: (v) =>
                              v.isEmpty ? 'Enter Your Answer' : null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Write Your Answer Here',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '2/ ' + question2,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: question2Controller,
                          validator: (v) =>
                              v.isEmpty ? 'Enter Your Answer' : null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Write Your Answer Here',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '3/ ' + question3,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: question3Controller,
                          validator: (v) =>
                              v.isEmpty ? 'Enter Your Answer' : null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Write Your Answer Here',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '4/ ' + question4,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: question4Controller,
                          validator: (v) =>
                              v.isEmpty ? 'Enter Your Answer' : null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Write Your Answer Here',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 10, 0, 10),
                            child: Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Text(
                                  '5/ ' + question5,
                                  textAlign: TextAlign.left,
                                  maxLines: null,
                                ),
                              ],
                            )),
                        TextFormField(
                          controller: question5Controller,
                          validator: (v) =>
                              v.isEmpty ? 'Enter Your Answer' : null,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
                          maxLines: null,
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            labelText: 'Write Your Answer Here',
                          ),
                        ),
                        Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                          child: Container(
                              child: Padding(
                                  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
                                  child: Column(
                                    children: <Widget>[
                                      FloatingActionButton.extended(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          _showAlertDialog(context);
                                        },
                                        label: Text(
                                          "Submit",
                                          style: TextStyle(
                                              fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                                        ),
                                        backgroundColor: Colors.amber,
                                      ),
                                    ],
                                  ))),
                        ),
                      ]),
                )));
  }
}
```

***stu_case_study_model.dart***

```
class CaseStudyModel {
  String title,
      description,
      body,
      question1,
      question2,
      question3,
      question4,
      question5;

  CaseStudyModel(this.title, this.description, this.body, this.question1,
      this.question2, this.question3, this.question4, this.question5);
}
```

***stu_caseStudies_list.dart***

List of Case studies Page

```
import 'package:firebase_database/firebase_database.dart';
import 'package:firebase_database/ui/firebase_animated_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/functions/Student/class_case_study_list.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/functions/database.dart';
import 'package:virtulab/student/stu_case_study_view.dart';


class CaseStudiesList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _CaseStudiesList();
  }
}

class _CaseStudiesList extends State<CaseStudiesList> {
  Query _caseStudyTitle;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _caseStudyTitle = firebaseref.child('case_study');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        title: Text('Case Studies'),
        backgroundColor: Colors.deepPurple,
      ),
      body: FirebaseAnimatedList(
        query: _caseStudyTitle,
        defaultChild: Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator()),
        itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, snapshot,
            Animation<double> animation, int index) {
          Map caseStudy = snapshot.value;
          caseStudy['key'] = snapshot.key;
          return _caseStudyList(caseStudy: caseStudy);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _caseStudyList({Map caseStudy}) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Card(
          child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {},
            child: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
              // padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
              // height: 70,
              color: Colors.white,
              child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20, 10, 20, 10),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            Icon(
                              Icons.description_sharp,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(width: 20),
                            Column(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                              children: [
                                Text(
                                  caseStudy['title'],
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                      fontSize: 16,
                                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                      height: 2,
                                      color: Colors.deepPurple),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        ElevatedButton(
                            onPressed: () => {
                                  Navigator.push(
                                    context,
                                    MaterialPageRoute(
                                      builder: (context) => CaseStudyView(
                                          //csKey: caseStudy['key'],
                                          ),
                                    ),
                                  )
                                },
                            child: Text('Start'),
                            // color: Colors.amber,
                            style: ButtonStyle(
                                backgroundColor:
                                    MaterialStateProperty.all<Color>(
                                        Colors.amber))),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  SizedBox(height: 5),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

This is my graduation project and I sincerely appreciate your help. Thank you.